# How does an anonymous function know its name?

Tags: javascript, first-class-functions

Consider the following code.

```js
const foo = () => {};
console.log(foo.name); // prints foo
const bar = foo;
console.log(bar.name); // prints foo again
```

Please point out what is wrong with my reasoning about the statement `const foo = () => {};`.  The expression `() => {}` evaluates to an anonymous function object and the statement binds the name `foo` to that object. Surely the value of the expression `() => {}` does not know it has `name` `foo`, but somehow it knows after `foo` is bound to it. But how did that happen? I assume that `=` does not alter the right-hand side and lines 3 and 4 behave as I expected.

Comment: Because those aren't anonymous functions, they're function expressions. Here's some further reading on the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/519413

Comment: Yes, it infers its name from its syntactic position. So `const foo = () => {}` sets the `.name` property on the Function you just created. When you reassign the reference, `.name` has already been set which is why `const bar = foo` has `bar.name === 'foo'`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#variable_declaration_and_method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the specification, when [a variable declaration is evaluated](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and the *initializer* is an anonymous function definition, then that definition is evaluated in a special way, passing along the name of the variable to be used as function name:

> *LexicalBinding* : *BindingIdentifier* *Initializer*
> 1. Let *bindingId* be [StringValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-stringvalue) of *BindingIdentifier*.
> 2. Let *lhs* be ! [ResolveBinding](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-resolvebinding)(*bindingId*).
> 3. If [IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isanonymousfunctiondefinition)(*Initializer*) is `true`, then
>    a. Let value be ? [NamedEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation) of *Initializer* with argument *bindingId*.
> ...

Something similar happens when evaluating an assignment expression.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1 of your code technically isn't an anonymous function, it's a "implicitly named" [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) (or as the mdn also calls it, an "unnamed function").

From the mdn:

> The variable to which the function expression is assigned will have a name property. The name doesn't change if it's assigned to a different variable. **If function name is omitted, it will be the variable name (implicit name).** If function name is present, it will be the function name (explicit name). This also applies to arrow functions (arrows don't have a name so you can only give the variable an implicit name).

See also: [Function.name#function_expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#function_expression)